# Nodejs express populate sub array data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have relative field and in relative I have subRelatives and it continues like nested array. Mean in subRelatives I have subRelatives and some time its 10 times continues process.

My code

```
router.get(`/userTree/:id`, async (req, res) => {
    const userTrees = await Tree.find({createdBy: req.params.id})
        .populate(
            ["createdBy",
                {
                    path: "relatives",
                    populate: {
                        path: "subRelatives",
                        populate: {
                            path: "subRelatives",
                            populate: "subRelatives",
                        },
                    },
                }
            ]);

    if (!userTrees) {
        res.status(500).json({success: false});
    }

    res.send({success: true, data: userTrees});
});
```

I have added populate but it populate first 2 sub relative and then shows MongooseIds only without populating. So I need to added manually some more populate methods so it will run but its crashing because of lot of data now.

and data look like this.

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "_id": "62dad5c6aff2337dc84d9b40",
        "treeName": "test1",
        "createdBy": {
            "_id": "62d8619cebd6543477c5b7d8",
            "userName": "test1",
            "userEmail": "test1@gmail.com",
            "userFamilyTrees": [
                "62d8c713547ba80854d89d59"
            ]
        },
        "relatives": [
            {
                "_id": "62dad5c7aff2337dc84d9b44",
                "firstName": "tesads",
                "subRelatives": [
                    {
                        "_id": "62db1cf186b7012ed9937517",
                        "firstName": "asdasd",
                        "subRelatives": []
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "62db1d0d86b7012ed9937522",
                        "firstName": "asd",
                        "subRelatives": []
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "62dc24c15e6f5ea436cce14b",
                        "firstName": "julia",
                        "subRelatives": [
                            {
                                "_id": "62dc24c15e6f5ea436cce14b",
                                "firstName": "julia",
                                "subRelatives": [
                                    "62dc253bd2119bea52f4f9af"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "62dc24fcd2119bea52f4f99d",
                        "firstName": "julia",
                        "subRelatives": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is my Tree Schema

const mongoose = require('mongoose')

```
const treeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    treeName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }, image: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    treePrivacy: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true
    },
    treeNote: {
        type: String,
        default: ""
    },
    createdBy: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users',
        required: true,
    },
    createDate: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
    },
    relatives: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'relatives',
    },],
    usersInTree: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users',
    },],
    media: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'media',
    },]
});



treeSchema.virtual('treeID').get(function () {
    return this._id.toHexString();
});

treeSchema.set('toJSON', {
    virtuals: true
})

exports.Tree = mongoose.model('trees', treeSchema)

exports.treeSchema = treeSchema;
```

This is relative Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const relativeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
    }, image: {
        type: String,
    },
    relativeEmail: {
        type: String,
    },
    relativeType: {
        type: Number,
    },
    // relative grandfather0, father1, mother2, wife3, sister4, brother5, child6
    treeID: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users',
        required: true,
    },
    subRelatives: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'relatives',
    }],
    parentRelative: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'relatives',
    },
    userID: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'relatives',
        required: false
    }
});

relativeSchema.virtual('relativeId').get(function () {
    return this._id.toHexString();
});

relativeSchema.set('toJSON', {
    virtuals: true
})

exports.Relatives = mongoose.model('relatives', relativeSchema)

exports.relativeSchema = relativeSchema;
```

This is post api for tree

```
router.post('/createTree', uploadOptions.single('image'), async (req, res) => {
    const file = req.file;
    if (!file) return res.status(400).send('No image in the request');

    const fileName = file.filename;
    const basePath = `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/public/uploads/`;
    var userintree = [];


    const userExist = await User.findById(req.body.createdBy);
    if (!userExist) return res.status(400).send({ success: false, message: 'UserID   is not correct' })
    userintree.push(req.body.createdBy);

    let createtree = new Tree({
        treeNote: req.body.treeNote,
        treeName: req.body.treeName,
        treePrivacy: req.body.treePrivacy,
        createdBy: req.body.createdBy,
        image: `${basePath}${fileName}`,
        usersInTree: userintree
    });

    createtree = await createtree.save();
    if (!createtree) return res.status(400).send({ success: false, message: 'Issue to create a tree' })


    userExist.userFamilyTrees.push(createtree._id.toHexString())
    const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.body.createdBy,
        {
            userFamilyTrees: userExist.userFamilyTrees,
            $push: {
                usersInTree: req.body.createdBy
            }

        },

        { new: true }
    )
    if (user) res.status(200).send({ success: true, message: 'Tree Created.!,', data: createtree })
});
```

and post API for relative

```
router.post('/addRelative', uploadOptions.single('image'), async (req, res) => {
    const file = req.file;
    if (!file) return res.status(400).send('No image in the request');

    const fileName = file.filename;
    const basePath = `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/public/uploads/`;
    console.log(fileName); console.log(basePath);
    console.log(req.body);
    let createRelative = new Relatives({
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        relativeEmail: req.body.relativeEmail,
        relativeType: req.body.relativeType,
        treeID: req.body.treeID,
        subRelatives: req.body.subRelatives,
        parentRelative: req.body.parentRelative, image: `${basePath}${fileName}`,

    });
    const treeExist = await Tree.findById(req.body.treeID);
    if (!treeExist) return res.status(400).send({ success: false, message: 'TreeID is not correct' })
    createRelative = await createRelative.save();
    if (!createRelative)
        return res.status(400).send({ success: false, message: 'Something Went Wrong.!,' })
    treeExist.relatives.push(createRelative._id.toHexString())

    const tree = await Tree.findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.body.treeID,
        {
            relatives: treeExist.relatives
        },
        { new: true }
    )

    if (req.body.parentRelative) {
        console.log(req.body.parentRelative)

        const parent = await Relatives.findById(
            req.body.parentRelative
        );
        // console.log(parent)
        // console.log(parent)

        parent.subRelatives.push(createRelative)
        const user = await Relatives.findByIdAndUpdate(
            req.body.parentRelative,
            {
                subRelatives: parent.subRelatives,
            },
            { new: true }
        )
        // console.log(user)
        if (!user) return res.status(400).send({ success: false, message: 'Something Went Wrong.!,' })

        // res.send(ser);
    }


    res.status(200).send({ success: true, message: 'Relative Created Created.!,', data: createRelative })
});
```

Comment: if you check the data, it shows some circular data. Please check your model and how are you storing the data.

Answer (score 0):

Populate data like this

```
  .populate(
            ["createdBy",
                {
                    path: "relatives",
                    populate: {
                        path: "subRelatives",
                        model: "SubRelative",
                    },
                }

            ]);
```

I've assumed that the model name refaring to subRelative is `SubRelative`

Answer (score 0):

`mongoose` does support nested population, it's just that you need to specify the `model` field as the `treeSchema`  does not have access to all other schema during run time. It looks like this:

```
const userTrees = await Tree.find({createdBy: req.params.id})
    .populate(
        [
            "createdBy",
            {
                path: "relatives",
                populate: {
                    path: "subRelatives",
                    model: 'relatives',
                },
            }
        ]);
```

`mongoose` does some optimizations to the query, but considering you know the exact structure you can reduce db calls and improve performance if you do this yourself instead of using `populate`.

Comment: I have tried with the model but it just populates the first two arrays then again it's showing the ids only not populating them. If I add manually populate in the populate method then it's working which I don't want because the array of sub relative is so long

Comment: You have to keep manually nesting this, do you have a max depth you know of?